# How to generate a function from a given graph?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Please provide any formula or step-by-step guide on how to generate a function for the following graph.

**Graph logic:**

Part 1 $\longrightarrow$ where $x \leq 3$ $\longrightarrow$ linear relation.

Part 2 $\longrightarrow$ when $3 \leq x \leq 6$ $\longrightarrow$ $y$ remains unchanged.

Then, again part 1 with $3 < x < 9$ $\longrightarrow$ linear relation.

Then part 2 when $y$ remains unchanged.

[image]

Thanks!

EDIT:
Values for $x$ and $y$

| *x* | *y* |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 11 | 5 |
| 12 | 6 |
| 13 | 6 |
| 14 | 6 |
| 15 | 6 |
| 16 | 6 |
| 17 | 6 |

and so on.

I am trying to create an interpolator for the following case:

```
Interpolation time 3500 ms
Value start = 0, end = 1
```

Firstly, the `500 ms` value increases by the formula `(end/3500)*interpolated time`.

Then `1000 ms` value remains unchanged.

Then `500 ms` again value increases.

Then `1000 ms` value remains unchanged.

Then `500 ms` again value increases.

Comment: What is the value of $f(x) = y$ in the interval $[3, 9]$? You have to construct a piecewise function. Define $f(x)$ on separate intervals of $x$, just like you have verbally done in your question.

Comment: Do you know how to get the equation of of line if you are given two points on the line?  When you ask a question here it helps a lot if you tell us what you have tried and what you know about the question.  Otherwise, we don't know where to start with an answer.

Comment: @Joshiepillow Thanks, thats was my mistake

Comment: @saulspatz I've updated my question with a bit more explanations. Please check it

Comment: @JacobCheverie I've updated my question with a bit more explanations. Please check it

Comment: All you need is the $xy$-coordinates at the endpoints of the intervals.  Then you just use the [equation of the line segment joining them](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Two-PointForm.html) in that interval.

Answer (score 0):

$y = x - 2a/3$ for $a \leq x < a + 3$

$y = a/3 +3$ for $a+3 \leq x < a + 9$

Where $a$ is defined as all numbers for which $a \bmod 9 = 0$.

Basically, $a$ is divisible by 9.

Tried this on Desmos. It works but you’ll have to manually type in every value of $a$.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use discrete functions, you can use sigmoid approximation.

$$f_1(x) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1 + e^{-k(x)}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + e^{k(x-3)}}$$

The above function will return approximately $0$ if $x$ is not in the interval $(0,3)$, otherwise $1$. Likewise you can create your own functions for other intervals.

\begin{align}
f_2(x) &= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1 + e^{-k(x-3)}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + e^{k(x-9)}} \\
f_3(x) &= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1 + e^{-k(x-9)}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + e^{k(x-12)}} \\
f_4(x) &= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1 + e^{-k(x-12)}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + e^{k(x-17)}}
\end{align}

Now, multiply all the functions with their lines.

$$f(x) = f_1 \cdot x + f_2 \cdot 3 + f_3 \cdot (x-6) + f_4 \cdot 6$$

Here is an example MATLAB code and the result graph.

[image: Matlab code and graph]